# Equivalent in HERE Lite to HERE Starter PositioningManager

Tags: android, position, mapping, here-api

HERE Starter API is deprecated in favour HERE Lite API. What is the equivalent to Starter's PositioningManager and is there a sample/example of its use.

Comment: Please refer following link for the sample code for HERE lite API : developer.here.com/documentation/android-sdk/dev_guide/topics/examples.html

Comment: That's unhelpful. To be more precise I wish to find the current location using the HERE Lite API. In the app I'm writing originally in the HERE Starter API I used the PositioningManager. The Starter API is now deprecated and so I'm rewriting what I've done using the Lite API. I looked at the examples first but none seemed to provide this functionality and the Lite documentation is pretty terse. Do you have an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the moment of writing this (12/2019), the HERE SDK 4.1 (Lite) has no own positioning system included. 
Suggestions are to use normal location APIs from the Platform at this point of time.